# how do I make the image lined to the bottom of the page?

Tags: image

I have a problem with my footer, I want to put my image up higher so that the bottom of it will be even with the copy right info. I'm using HTML 5 and CSS 3, that image is below the copy right info, I have tried everything I can think of to make the image float up to where I can think of and now I'm asking you guys for help.

here is my html

```
<div class="main-footer">
<div class="footer">
    <article class="contact-us">
        <h2>CONTACT US</h2><br>

        <p>Email: <a href="#">
        info@#</a></p><br>
        <p>Personnel Network Incorporated<br>
        address <br>
        address</p><br>
        <p>Phone: </p><br>                      

        <footer class="copyright">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2013 Personnel 
            Network, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>

        <img alt="PNI logo" src="Images/pni-logo.jpg">  

    </article>  
</div>
```

And here is the css

```
    .footer {
    color: #729AA9;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-us {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 3%;
}

.contact-us a {
    color: #1C5ACB;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: black;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.contact-us img {
    width: 230px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vertically align your copyright and image to the bottom, so that the bottom of the copyright and the bottom of the image line up:

Updated CSS:

```
.contact-us div {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: black;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact-us img {
    width: 230px;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <article class="contact-us">
        <h2>CONTACT US</h2><br>

        <p>Email: <a href="#">
        info@#</a></p><br>
        <p>Personnel Network Incorporated<br>
        address <br>
        address</p><br>
        <p>Phone: </p><br>                      

        <div class="footer-wrapper-class">
            <footer class="copyright">
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2013 Personnel 
                Network, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
            </footer>

            <img alt="PNI logo" src="Images/pni-logo.jpg">  
        </div>

    </article>  
</div>
```

This will actually move your copyright down to the same height as the bottom of the image (rather than moving your image up). If this is too low, you can add this CSS:

```
.footer-wrapper-class {
    margin-top: -10px; // Set this to whatever amount you want to move them up
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZW7X/

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work, I don't know why else to do I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I updated the answer. Should be working now.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, that has been driving me nuts. Thanks again.